# How return back original SimpleDraweeView after blurring

Tags: java, android, imageview, fresco

I've have SimpleDraweeView(Fresco). How can I return back original image after blurring?

Blur code:

```
val blurController = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
   .setImageRequest(
       ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
           .setPostprocessor(IterativeBoxBlurPostProcessor(7))
           .build()
   )
   .setOldController(image.controller)
   .build()

image.controller = blurController
```

Comment: What do you want to do with original unblurred image?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `uri` for `SimpleDraweeView` like this:

```
var offBlur=view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.blur_off)
offBlur.setOnClickListener { 
    image.setImageURI(uri)  // this line
}
```

After set `uri` again, blur effect will disappear.